# Can you merge in TFS based on a solution file?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge

Instead of merging by file/directory hierarchy manually, I would like to set up a strict list of files to be merged on specific instances. The SLN solution file that contains all the files needed in my workspace would be the ideal candidate but I have found no way to merge based on it.

Comment: What files are in your folders in TFS which are not in your solution?

Comment: @JohnSaunders For the purpose of this question, the answer is none. I actually only need to merge all the files in the solution (projects with their contents, referenced DLLs, the .sln file itself, etc.). The problem is that in TFS you merge file by file or directory by directory, and with the current folder structure I need to be very careful to not forget certain files. It would be a lot easier of the solution would be the driver.

Comment: I hope that the referenced DLLs are properly in their own folder in source control, and that you haven't been checking in `bin` folders? In any case, if all the files you want to merge from the solution are already in your folders, then why isn't it the same thing to merge folders?

Comment: @JohnSaunders All projects and referenced DLLs (all objects in the solution, let's say) are spread across the directory structure in various places. Merging each of these objects one by one provides room for human error (a developer can forget to merge the ThirdPartyLibraries folder for example, so now a DLL is not updated in the Main branch). Also, it is a tedious manual process. Merging all of the objects that a solution includes would be both an easier and error-free merge. After all, the build definitions are by solution, so it only makes sense to merge by solution's contents too, right?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Regarding /bin folders - no, they are not in discussion here. Whenever I say DLL in the text above, I mean third party DLLs which some projects reference, not the output of our own code.